# How can I precisely replicate this text shadow effect?

Tags: gimp, text, effects, shadows

[image]

I want to be able to start with the raw white text (font is bank gothic) and replicate the shadow effect pixel for pixel (or as closely as possible).

I have tried many different blur effects in GIMP but just can't get it looking exactly the same.

Comment: Copy the layer, paste it, modify it, repeat - [technologic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OunOdnaj5y0)

Comment: I'm looking for a more algorithmic approach as i want to apply the effect to any possible text and if i apply the effect to the same text but at different times, each result should be identicle.

Comment: You can do that approach algorithmically

Comment: Additionally you can make this into an action to run on any text.

Comment: IMHO isn't (only) a blur... What I see is that there are overlapping copies of the characters each with an individual random  vertical and horizontal displacement. But since the important word is "random" "pixel for pixel" is going to be difficult. the [ofn-text-along-path script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) can generate a text path where each character is randomly displaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something quite similar (not "precisely") can be done semi-automatically with the [Layer Effects plug-in](http://registry.gimp.org/node/186) in GIMP, and a little extra manual work.

To install the plugin save the *layerfx.2.8.py* file in your GIMP plug-ins folder, and relaunch the application.

With a text layer selected, click *Layers > Layer Effects > Drop Shadow*

Use these settings shown below. You may need to adjust the size and distance setting depending on the size of the text.

[image]

Then you could select the green shadow layer, apply a transform (Shift+T) to stretch it horizontally, and squish it vertically a bit.

[image]

This is the result

[image]

It's also possible to duplicate the green shadow layer, and adjust the position and opacities, and get something a bit more random

[image]